# How do I chat about a specific question?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, not-constructive, deleted-comments

My comment just got erased. Epic. Anyway, I dont know much about chat here. How do I engage in chatting about a specific question. Do I just say something in the chat and post a link to the question. Or what?

Comment: Posting a link to the question will help, that's for sure. After that, just ask whatever questions you have.

Comment: The chat link is under the Stack Exchange drop down, if you didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

If you post a link to the question or answer you want to talk about (using the link from the "share" link under each post) on a line by itself in chat it will one-box to a nice link to it, then you can say whatever you'd like to in relation to that.

The main chat room is fine for most topics, but if an extensive ongoing theological discussion gets going sometimes we make custom rooms (e.g. There is a room just for all things Creation/Evolution related).